# Access Facebook object delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting to a users Facebook wall with code similar to this:

```
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                  andParams:params
              andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                andDelegate:self];
```

If I dismiss the hosting UIViewController before the request completes, I get a crash when the request does actually complete because the delegate has been dealloc'd.

Is there any way I can get around this? I don't really want to make a high level object like my appDelegate the FB delegate, this seems silly.

There's a good description of the problem I'm facing here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller's dealloc method, set the Facebook object's delegate to nil.  In your case that would look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    appDelegate.facebook.sessionDelegate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When the request completes, the delegate method will get called on the nil object, which will swallow the message silently.

This is a good habit to get into any time you set `self` as the delegate on any object.

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem, but it does look like the answer to my actual question, so thanks. I ended up solving my problem by switching to ASIHttpRequest.